# Trigger jQuery After an Ajax Call - Plugin Ajax Layered Navigation - WooCommerce

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

having searched I have found similar issues but none directly relating to my problem or a solution that works for me. My jQuery Knowledge isn't too strong so it could be something nice and simple.

Here Goes...

• I have a WooCommerce website and have installed the Ajax Layered Navigation Plugin to filter down categories.

• To add specific styling to these I have the following jQuery function to add a class to each li

```js
$('.checkboxes li').each(function(){
$(this).addClass("filter_" + $(this).text());
});
```

• This works great up until a filter is selected.

• Once the page is reloaded the above classes get removed.

• I have looked to combine a number of different options around ajaxSuccess and ajaxComplete however cannot get the function to re-fire.

---

What I need to know is how to re-trigger the event above so that each time the page reloads / filters via ajax the appropriate class gets added to that li.

[This is the code before Ajax takes place, all li's have the right class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twI2s.png)

[This image shows the Li's after the filter has been clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbyU5.png)

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function( event,request, settings ) { 
    $( "#products" ).append( "<li>Request Complete.</li>" ); 
});

$( document ).ajaxSuccess(function() { 
    $('.checkboxes li').each(function(){
        $(this).addClass("filter_" + $(this).text());
    });
}); 

$(document).ajaxSuccess(function(){ 
    alert("AJAX request successfully completed");
});
```

Many Thanks in advance for any Help!

Comment: Make sure you write this code inside `$(document).ready` function

Comment: Thanks Krunal, the function in the question is already within a $(document).ready - which I understand loads the function on page load and works well. The issue I have Is when the page is reloaded via ajax this function does not re-trigger. Thanks for the quick response though!

Comment: Can you share URL?

Comment: Unfortunately unable share the URL on here due to NDA

Comment: Okay no issues if it's updating after ajax then `ajaxComplete` will be helpful for this please write inside it and try to alert and check is that giving alert or not - https://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/ and also check within `setTimeout` inside `ajaxComplete` because it took little time to update dropdown so

Comment: `$(document).ajaxSuccess(...) ` would be my way to attemtpt it. Did you try anything of that sort? Can you show us what you attempted?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Krunal, this is unfortunately above my knowledge of jQuery. I have looked to set up an alert but to no joy.

Comment: Thanks @user3154108  I did try a few similar looking solutions to that however all with no success. A few different attempts are below, most of the code if tried I have removed however this lot is still commented out.

Comment: 'code' // $( document ).ajaxComplete(function( event,request, settings ) {
//   $( "#products" ).append( "<li>Request Complete.</li>" );
// });
//  $( document ).ajaxSuccess(function() {
// // $('.checkboxes li').each(function(){
// //   $(this).addClass("filter_" + $(this).text());
// // });
//  });
 // $(document).ajaxSuccess(function(){
 //    alert("AJAX request successfully completed");
 //  });

 'code'

Comment: Some of this code is just trying to trigger an alert etc to see if I could get anything to work after filter was clicked. Thanks.

Comment: hm, I just read on the Docs: `If $.ajax() or $.ajaxSetup() is called with the global option set to false, the .ajaxSuccess() method will not fire. ` maybe that is what the plugin does.

Comment: @user3154108 thanks for getting back to me. Your suggestion has lead me to try firing off the alert when a separate Ajax option is triggered. Triggering this new bit of ajax gives the alert! Code used is this. 
 $(document).ajaxSuccess(function(){
    alert("AJAX request successfully completed");
  });

Comment: From your findings I am assuming that my method above will not work with the Ajax Layered Navigation Plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting a timeout after ajax complete?

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() { 

    setTimeout(function(){ 

      alert("Ajax done"); 

      $('.checkboxes li').each(function(){
        $(this).addClass("filter_" + $(this).text());
      });

    }, 500); 

});
```